# Clickable label not working in IE 8

Tags: javascript, html

I've got the following list item:

```
<li>
    <input value="someRadioButton" name="ctl00$mainContent$group" type="radio"
        id="ctl00_mainContent_somelRadioButton" onclick="showSomeInfo()" />
    <label for="ctl00_mainContent_someRadioButton">
        <img class="extraPadding-Right-10" src="https://xxy.com/some_mark_37x23.gif" />
    </label>
</li>
```

So what shows up is a radio button and an image next to it.  When I am in FireFox, Chrome, and Safari clicking on that image fires the showSomeInfo() that's specified in the radio's onclick.  I'm not sure why I guess because it's wrapped in a label and that label is relating to that radio button....

But anyway that's not my problem.  I like that when you click the image, that javascript method showSomeInfo() is called.  But the problem is that it works in all browsers except IE 8.  If I open this page in IE 8, clicking on the image does nothing and I'm not sure why.  I'm baffled at this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason it works the way it does in Firefox et al is that that's what `<label>` is supposed to do when it's got a "for" attribute that points to an input field (by "id" value). If it doesn't work that way in IE, it's because Microsoft either interpreted the standard differently or simply failed to implement it correctly. (I don't see any clear language in the w3c reference I found to stipulate whether anything but text content of a label should get focus and transfer it.)

Comment: I played around with it a but too. Can't get it to work with an image. Text is OK.

Comment: This is not a constructive answer and provides no solutions to the problem.

Comment: @Christopher it was an accurate answer in April of 2010. Internet Explorer was broken in various ways in its handling of `<label>` elements. Now it's 2016, and the world is a lot different of course. Also note that though you say the answer provides no solutions to the problem, the OP selected it as answering the question.

Comment: @Christopher Well I'd always prefer an actual solution, sometimes the right answer is, "It can't be done". Like if someone asks, "How can I build a perpetual motion machine?", I wouldn't say that anyone who replies "it's impossible" is being non-responsive!

Comment: Reality is more complicated than this. I'm having exactly the same problem in an ASP.NET program. But when I create a simple HTML file, it works fine. This works: "<input id="chk21" name="chk21" type="checkbox" class="customcheck2" onclick="alert('click');" /><label for="chk21"><img src="icon-dark-20-plus.png"/><img src="icon-dark-20-plusdown.png"/></label>" Ok, that's in IE11, so maybe something has changed since this thread was originally posted.

Comment: @Jay this is a 10 year old question :)

Comment: Sure, but the problem still exists in IE 11. You don't expect Microsoft to get a bug fixed in only 10 years, do you?

Answer (score 17):

I was looking for an answer to this and wrote a quick dirty jquery handler for it:

```
$("label").click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr("for") != "")
        $("#" + $(this).attr("for")).click();
});
```

Comment: The `focus` event should be used, not `click`. Also, I'm pretty sure `this.for` would work, so you don't have to create new jQuery objects

Comment: Focus event doesn't fire oddly enough, so I had to use click. this.for doesn't work, it is a reserved word: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words.  You can use this.getAttribute('for')

Comment: using javascript: `if(this.htmlFor)`

Comment: This didn´t work for me, because instead of a Radio Button, I´m trying to fire a Input File, and them, I get access denied.

Comment: becareful: this might destory chrome and firefox functionality

Comment: In chrome and firefox, if you have click events, they will fire twice.

Comment: This code snippet didn't work for me, particularly in non-IE browsers where the label click fired in a loop triggered by the radio click. I've amended this solution though slightly to come up with something that seems to work for me in all browsers. [See my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34890857/193617).

Answer (score 14):

There's a slightly cleaner approach to change the markup that doesn't involve (ugly) CSS hacks or Javascript; change the `<img>` tag to a `<span>` tag with a background-image of the appropriate size. For example:

```
<li>
  <input value="someRadioButton" name="ctl00$mainContent$group" type="radio"
         id="ctl00_mainContent_somelRadioButton" onclick="showSomeInfo()" />
  <label for="ctl00_mainContent_someRadioButton">
    <span class="extraPadding-Right-10" style="background-image: url(https://xxy.com/some_mark_37x23.gif); width: 100px; height: 100px; display: inline-block" />
  </label>
</li>
```

Replacing the width and height of your image appropriately.

Answer (score 7):

I've also discovered that if you have a hidden input with `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` and are relying on the label for selection it will not work in ie8.

My workaround was to have an `overflow:hidden` on the containing element and position the input outside of this area.

Comment: This little observation just turned my morning around.  Thanks for reporting.

Comment: This should be the best answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I Guess I have a better hack solution for this problem.
I will explain why for first.

Using jquery to hit the label click works, but not when you are using an Input File, because you will receive access denied.

Using css and display the image as a background it´s not good too because you need to have an image with the exactly size, which is not the case when the user uploads the Image or you have a lot of images with different sizes.

**Ok now I´ll explain the idea of the hack:**

You have a Label with an image inside, when you click the image, IE8 doesn´t fire the Label. But if you write some text into the Label, when you click the text IE8 fire the label.

The Idea is to **put a span inside the label, with the size of the label (width and height)**

Ok but if you don´t have text inside it won´t work, but if you change the background color it will work.

So what you need to do is:

1. Place a Span with the role size of the Label
2. Write a background color and make it transparent
3. Position the Span using relative position to put the Span exactly over the Label.

It´s a little hard to do it, but I guess it will cover many more situations.
An example of a Label firing the Input type File:

```
<label for="" id="lblInput" style="cursor: pointer; z-index:3;">
    <img src="../Imagens/SemPerfil.jpg" ID="imgFoto" Style="max-width: 280px; max-height: 180px;z-index:2;" />
    <span style="position:relative;
        top:-180px;display:block;height:180px;width:280px;
        z-index:1;background-color:Aqua;
        -ms-filter:'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=1)';
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);" >
    </span>
</label>
```

I hope it works and save you Like it saved-me

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you aren't simply looking at a typo?
Check "**ctl00_mainContent_someRadioButton**" vs. "**ctl00_mainContent_somelRadioButton**"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like IE doesn't properly handle labels with img elements in them. The only reasonable ways I have been able to find for dealing with this problem are either [using HTML component behaviors](http://jeffhowden.com/code/javascript/label_img/), [Javascript handlers](http://www.tsd.net.au/blog/using-images-labels-fix-ie), or [CSS hacks](http://haslayout.net/css/Image-Label-Focus-Bug). I haven't tried all of these so I can't guarantee that they will work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried some of the other solutions posted here and eventually amended them to get a working fix to your problem. My problem was similar, though the HTML looked a little different, with the LABEL tag wrapping both the image and the INPUT radio button.

The solution I include below will ensure that any `onClick` handlers fire correctly on the radio button itself. It also does this only once and not in browsers where the radio button label behaves normally.

This is the jQuery code I used to solve the problem in Internet Explorer 11:

```
$('LABEL > IMG').click(function () {
    var inputId = $(this).parents('LABEL:first').attr("for");
    if (inputId) $('#' + inputId).not(':checked').attr('checked', true).click();
});
```

The code above uses the jQuery method `attr()` to manipulate the `checked` property. If you're using jQuery 1.6 or higher you should modify this to use the jQuery method `prop()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with a group of radio inputs followed by labels containing an image. Basically used it instead of using for attribute in all browsers

```
      inputs.each(function() {

         $(this).click(function (e) {
             // do stuff ...
         });

        // adding click handler to label containing image 
        $(this).next().on('click', function(event) {
            // prevent 'for' attribute firing
            event.preventDefault();
            // check and trigger click on input
            $(this).prev().prop("checked", true).trigger('click');
        });
     });
```