# Clickable img wrapped in label not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have the following markup and Javascript:

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/ft4Hb/)**

HTML:

```
<form method="get" action="some-url-here">
 <div class="UserFilter">
  <ul class="UserFilter">
   <li>
      <label class="Selected" for="1">
          <input id="1" type="radio" value="1" name="Profile" />
          <img title="User 1" alt="User 1" src="img-url-here" style="width: 50px;height: 50px" />
          User 1
      </label>
   </li>
   <li>
      <label class="Selected" for="2">
          <input id="2" type="radio" value="2" name="Profile" />
          <img title="User 2" alt="User 2" src="img-url-here" style="width: 50px;height: 50px" />
          User 2
      </label>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var labelID;
$("label img").live("click", function() {
        labelID = $(this).parent().attr('for');
        $('#'+labelID).trigger('click');        
});

$('ul.UserFilter input').click(function () {
        $('ul.UserFilter input:not(:checked)').parent().removeClass("Selected");
        $('ul.UserFilter input:checked').parent().addClass("Selected");
        //$(this).closest("form").submit();     
});

$('input:checked').parent().addClass("Selected");
```

CSS:

```
div.UserFilter {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EAE5DA;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F1EEE6;
    border-top: 3px solid #0888A5;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #F1F1F1;
}
div.UserFilter ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
}
div.UserFilter ul li label.Selected {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0888A5;
    border: 1px solid #16758B;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #16758B;
}
div.UserFilter ul li label.Selected {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #688ABD;
    border: 1px solid #688ABD;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #52688A;
    transition: border-color 0.218s ease 0s;
}
div.UserFilter ul li label {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    padding: 0 5.666px 0 0;
    transition: background 0.218s ease 0s;
    word-spacing: normal;
}
```

Clicking on the text works just fine in selecting the radio button associated with it (tested in Firefox, Chrome and IE9+). However, in IE8-, clicking the image does not select or fire the click event of the radio button. Any ideas, workaround solutions, or suggestions are most welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like [Brad's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5601578/994820) to use a `<span>` with a background image. This way you get rid of the problem without having to use JavaScript.

Your HTML code becomes:

```
<form method="get" action="some-url-here">
 <div class="UserFilter">
  <ul class="UserFilter">
   <li>
      <label class="Selected" for="1">
          <input id="1" type="radio" value="1" name="Profile" />
          <span title="User 1" style="background-image: url('img-url-here')width: 50px;height: 50px;display: inline-block;"></span>
          User 1
      </label>
   </li>
   <li>
      <label class="Selected" for="2">
          <input id="2" type="radio" value="2" name="Profile" />
          <span title="User 2" style="background-image: url('img-url-here')width: 50px;height: 50px;display: inline-block;"></span>
          User 2
      </label>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</form>
```

The JavaScript gets much smaller. You can also remove the `$('input:checked').parent().addClass("Selected");` line, since you set the `Selected` class to your labels in the HTML code:

```
$('ul.UserFilter input').click(function () {
        $('ul.UserFilter input:not(:checked)').parent().removeClass("Selected");
        $('ul.UserFilter input:checked').parent().addClass("Selected");
        //$(this).closest("form").submit();     
});
```

The CSS stays the same, except you can remove one of the `div.UserFilter ul li label.Selected` selector.

An updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ft4Hb/1/

Comment: Cheers Andreas, replacing the img with the span tag did the trick but had to do a bit of css hack to display the background image.

Comment: @chridam You are right, I forgot to add `display: inline-block;` to make the images visible. It was in the fiddle, but not here.