# clicking label does not check radio box in ie8/9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

We are having an issue that is causing problems in IE 8 and IE 9. When the label is clicked then the radio box should then be checked. This is fine in all browsers apart from IE 8/9 where it does not check the radio button

```
<label for="so100">
    <img alt="" src="images/type6img.jpg" class="anitem1pic">
    <input type=radio value=1 name="site" id="so100" />
    <span class="anitem1">Stag</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Is your radio button supposed to be a child of your `label`? Because it should be a sibling of it, not a child.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your issue

Comment: I checked , its working

Comment: @mplungjan I'm finding it hard to understand, syntactically, why you would have the radio button as part of the label? Also, in my IE9 when I click on the image it doesn't check the radio button.

Comment: @RGraham - the solution is to not wrap. I never do. See my answer

Answer (score 8):

[Known IE "bug"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677933/clickable-label-not-working-in-ie-8) that a wrapped image does not trigger a radio

In [your example](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/NN7R5/show), the text works, the image does not:

Here is a duplicate with suggestions

[Clickable label not working in IE 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677933/clickable-label-not-working-in-ie-8)

Here is tested workaround based on  [Using images as labels in internet explorer](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/using_images_as). The solution in the article breaks Chrome. My wrapping in conditional comments prevents the script from breaking browsers that DO trigger on click. You can change `if IE` to `if IE8` if IE9 and 10 works like Chrome

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/AzDp9/show)

`<!--[if IE]>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("label img").on("click", function() {
    $("#" + $(this).parents("label").attr("for")).click();
  });
});
</script>
```

`<![endif]-->`

---

[My idea to have two labels](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/KBFTU/show/) did not work either since it is the image IE is complaining about.

```
<label for="so100">
  <img alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-50-50-8.jpg" class="anitem1pic">
</label>        

<input type=radio value=1 name="site" id="so100" />
<label for="so100">    
  <span class="anitem1">Stag</span>
</label>
```

Using a background image will work however

Comment: Thanks for the solution but it does not seem to work in ie 8/9

Comment: See solution in my latest update

Answer (score 0):

You should use this way ,and this works in all browsers :

```
<label for="radio1"> Option 1 </label> 
<input type="radio " id="radio1" name= "option" />

<label for="radio2"> Option 2 </label> 
<input type="radio " id="radio2" name= "option" />
```

Comment: But he wants to have two triggers. Wrapping in a label works except for images in IE.